# How to typeset telephone numbers properly?

Tags: typography

What is the proper way to typeset a telephone number? The number would be of the format:

```
Country-local-number-appendix
```

For example:

```
+31 6 21123234 5
```

(If these are the proper english terms...)

Comment: Disclaimer: I know that there probably isn't THE correct answer. Moreover, this might not even be the perfect place for such questions to be asked. But I know may people with great interest in typography roam this website and this question might be of interest for many of us!

Comment: There is a [LaTeX package `phonenumbers`](http://ctan.org/pkg/phonenumbers). Unfortunately, currently it supports only DE, FR and US. But you could help the author to provide more countries.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think that in these cases is good to refer to some standards, such as those of the International Telecommunication Union: [E.123 : Notation for national and international telephone numbers, e-mail addresses and web addresses.](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-E.123-200102-I/e) (Section **2 Notation for National and International Telephone Numbers**, of the English version).

Answer (score 13):

There is the [`telprint`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/telprint) package, but it is designed for the German format for telephone numbers.

Examples from the manual:

```
\telprint{0761/12345} ==> 07\,61/1\,23\,45
\telprint{01234/567-89} ==> 0\,12\,34/5\,67\leavevmode\hbox{-}89
\telprint{+49 (6221) 297} ==> +49~(62\,21)~2\,97
```

Answer (score 9):

The European Union recommendations can be found [here](http://publications.europa.eu/code/en/en-390300.htm).

> - Indicate the number in its international form.
> - Prefix the international dialling code with a plus sign ‘+’ (no following space) indicating the need to add the prefix for international calls.
> - After the international dialling code and a space, the complete number, including the regional code if there is one, is presented in a single block:
>
>   +33 140633900
> - An extension number is separated from the main number by a hyphen. Do not pair off the digits of an extension number. They appear in a single block:
>
>   +32 222020-43657

It goes without saying that this is the *worst* method possible to print a number in order to scan and remember it.

Comment: Also fails to deal with the 'omitted' part you get in code in, for example, UK phone numbers. (So my area code is 01604 if dialling in the UK, but you drop the leading zero from outside the UK.)

Comment: @JosephWright Of course: they simply seem not to know what telephone numbers are in the real world. That's rather common for EU bureaucrats.

Comment: About par for the course for the EU...

Answer (score 7):

There was a paper as to how the brain perceives and remembers numbers; grouping is important  in this respect. The paper made a particular mention of the French way of grouping numbers by two and the difficulty in remembering it this way. Formats depend on areas. I would not use any brackets or dashes, they just complicate the reading of the number. A simple

```
+971 4 294 0420
```

Comment: Sounds like an interesting paper. Do you have a citation?

Comment: I can't find the actual paper.  However if you interested in such things start with [Miller (1956)](http://www.psych.utoronto.ca/users/peterson/psy430s2001/Miller%20GA%20Magical%20Seven%20Psych%20Review%201955.pdf) who wrote, “The magical number seven
plus or minus two: demonstrating limits on our capacity
for processing information”.
2. Miller suggested that the
capacity of our short-term
memory was small. We could
store about 5-9 items in it.
3. He also showed that items could
be “chunked”, which would
increase our memory capacity. (The effect I describe in my answer)

Answer (score 6):

There is also a package [`phonenumbers`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/phonenumbers). Citing its summary:

"This pack­age makes it pos­si­ble to type­set tele­phone num­bers ac­cord­ing to dif­fer­ent na­tional con­ven­tions. Cur­rently, Ger­man, French, and North Amer­i­can phone num­bers are sup­ported. Phone num­bers from other coun­tries are sup­ported rudi­men­ta­r­ily.

The user can se­lect from var­i­ous for­mat­ting op­tions, in­clud­ing the ad­di­tional out­put of the coun­try call­ing code. The pack­age is able to check if a phone num­ber is valid ac­cord­ing to the na­tional rules. It also al­lows to link phone num­bers us­ing the hy­per­ref pack­age."

Comment: This package is maintained very actively.