# "+" sign in international phone numbers

Tags: symbols, addresses

I want a smaller "+" sign in international phone numbers. For example if I write

```
+1-123-456-7890
```

it gives

[image: +1-123-456-7890]

where "-" signs are all okay (not pretty though), but the "+" sign looks too big. How can I make it smaller? Is there any special symbol in LaTeX?

Comment: You can play around with `\raisebox{.3\height}{\scalebox{.7}{+}}` if you `\usepackage{graphicx}` in your preamble.

Comment: A related question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34152/8666, however the packages `telprint` and `phonenumbers` mentioned there use an ordinary `+` sign, as far as I could tell.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

An option could be to use + and - in monospaced font:

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\Plus{\texttt{+}}
\def\Minus{\texttt{-}}

\begin{document}

\Plus 1\Minus 123\Minus 456\Minus 7890

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks great IMHO. I would think that the thicker glyphs of `cmtt` would be disturbing, but they aren't!

Comment: I usually type the entire phone number in a monospaced font.

Comment: I see in this answer an improvement of the minus symbols: they are higher and appear to be at mid height of the numbers; for me, visually more pleasant.

Answer (score 29):

Here is an implementation of Werner's suggestion, which includes the definition of new commands `\plus` and `\minus` for the look of the symbols you want:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\plus}{\raisebox{.4\height}{\scalebox{.6}{+}}}
\newcommand{\minus}{\raisebox{.4\height}{\scalebox{.8}{-}}}
\begin{document}
Phone number \plus1\minus123\minus456\minus7890
\end{document}
```

Comment: You might want to ensure a consistent appearance of `+` and `-`. One way to do this is using the symbols from math mode:
`$+$1$-$123$-$456$-$7890`. Of course, these can be raised and scaled, but now by the same amount. (If you set the whole number in math mode, spacing will be inserted before and after the `-`, as they will be treated as operators then.)