# Short equals sign

Tags: fonts, symbols

I don't know much about font encodings in LaTeX, and I'm not running Xe(La)TeX. Does anyone know where I could find a shorter (as in: not as wide) equals sign? I use it in text, not in math, and it would be nice if it were as long as the hyphen symbol. I generally just use the standard Computer Modern fonts, but if the answer is to switch fonts or move to XeLaTex, I'd consider doing so.

Comment: If there is not an existing symbol you can use \scalebox or \resizebox from the graphicx package.

Comment: Related Question: [Is there a wider equal sign?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35404/is-there-a-wider-equal-sign/).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) allows for resizing things through `\resizebox{<width>}{<height>}{<stuff>}`. Here's what you could do:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\shorteq}{%
  \settowidth{\@tempdima}{-}% Width of hyphen
  \resizebox{\@tempdima}{\height}{=}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Here is a~-~hyphen, here is a~\shorteq~sign.\par
Here is a~-~hyphen, here is a~=~sign.
\end{document}
```

The above MWE provides `\shorteq` that squishes a `=` into the width of `-` of the prevailing font.

---

[`textcomp`](http://ctan.org/pkg/textcomp) also provides `\textdblhyphen` which is similar, but different:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcomp}% http://ctan.org/pkg/textcomp
\begin{document}
Here is a~-~hyphen, here is a~\textdblhyphen~sign.\par
Here is a~-~hyphen, here is a~=~sign.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! I like this answer because I can define the width of the equals as a multiple of the width of the hyphen. Looks great.

Comment: Is it possible to have something for math mode too?

Answer (score 9):

You can define your symbol using two rules:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\textequal{%
 \rule[.4ex]{4pt}{0.4pt}\llap{\rule[.7ex]{4pt}{0.4pt}}}

\begin{document}

text~\textequal~text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

If You have access to Unicode fonts you could also try U+FE66 (﹦) SMALL EQUALS SIGN compare (=|﹦) (In the fonts used by my browser in this web site SMALL EQUALS looks bigger than EQUALS, but mathematical typography isn't the strongest point about stackexchange:-)

Answer (score 3):

Inspired from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52519/30201):

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\Equal{\texttt{=}}

\begin{document}
    text~\Equal~text~=~text
\end{document}
```

[image: shortEqualSign]