# Plus Sign Too Big; How to Call adfbullet?

Tags: symbols

The + sign when typeset using Latin Modern in LaTeX is too big when used to indicate the international dialing country code.

According to the LaTeX comprehensive symbol list, the commands

```
\adfbullet{5}
```

or

```
\adfbullet{7}
```

will produce a symbol that seems to work. Unfortunately, adding \adfbullet{5} yields an "Undefined control sequence" error.

So, how to get the two symbols that should be produced by these two commands?

(And yes, I have seen ["+" sign in international phone numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52503/sign-in-international-phone-numbers)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should put `\usepackage{adfbullets}` in the preamble.

See http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/fonts/adfsymbols/adfsymbols.pdf (or run `texdoc adfbullets`) for further information.