# Always raise plus sign in text

Tags: symbols, positioning, text-mode, raise

I have a lot of places in my dissertation where the plus sign appears surrounded by capital letters in text, e.g. NNLL+NNLO.
The problem is that by default, the + is aligned so low vertically, that among caps it looks badly aligned.
By playing around with the `\raisebox`, I found that it looks quite a bit better if raised by `0.25ex`, and still looks fine with lowercase letters, even in situations like a+j.
Is there a way to change the default behavior of the plus sign to always appear raised in text?
I don't want to change what happens in the math mode.

I suppose a potential solution might be to globally substitute raw `+` by `\raisebox{0.25ex}{+}` (modulo the issue with space swallowing) or to make latex use a different font for rendering the +.
I just don't know if that's even possible.

---

Reporting on what I implemented based on the answers.
Here's the command I came up with that also accounts for **bold** and allows typesetting of two consecutive raised spaces with `\++`.

```
\makeatletter % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31660/35990
\newcommand*{\IfbfTF}{% detect bold font
  \ifx\f@series\my@test@bf
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}
\newcommand*{\my@test@bf}{bx}
\makeatother

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/567256/35990
\newcommand{\textplus}[1][+]{\raisebox{% font-independent height
  \dimexpr(\fontcharht\font`X-\height+\depth)/2\relax
}{\IfbfTF{$\bm{#1}$}{#1}}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\+{}{
  \peek_charcode_remove:NTF + {\textplus[++]}{\textplus[+]}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

`\peek_charcode_remove:NTF` requires the `expl3` package.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "issue with space swallowing" ? `+` and `\raisebox{0.25ex}{+}` (and my suggested `\+`) all have the same behaviour with respect to surrounding white space.

Comment: If you define `\newcommand\myplus{+}` and then write `\myplus a`, it is rendered as '+a' without a space. I assumed the same would also happen for `\newcommand\+{+}`, which seems to not be the case. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: + isn't a letter, so `\+` terminates at the `+` just as `\$` or `\%` but you hadn't mentioned a definition, so I thought you meant using `\raisebox{..}{+}` explicitly, which wouldn't drop spaces either.

Comment: I also assumed that however a global substitution of + would work, it would internally rely on a new command definition and thus have the usual space problem. I clearly don't understand when space are swallowed and when not.

Comment: not sure what you mean by a global substitution, you mean replacing + by `\resizebox{}{}` in your editor? Yes that would work as well.

Comment: Like I wrote in the question, I don't know if that is possible in latex, but one could imagine some mechanism that would allow any occurrence of a + in the text mode to be rendered as if `\raisebox{..}{+}` was written instead. For example, in C you can define macros that perform literal string substitutions in the source code before compilation. The analogy is not complete, because C macros are not context-aware.

Comment: as I said in my answer you could do that (same as `~` turns into `\nobreakspace`) but there are constructs that would break where + is used in arithmetic expressions. If you are feeling brave, define `\~` as in my or egreg's answer then do `\catcode\`\+=\active \def+{\relax\ifmmode\string+\else\+\fi}`   (TeX consists almost entirely of macro expansion in the sense of C macros, and nothing in the sense of C compiled functions)

Comment: I agree now that `\+` seems a better option than redefining the `+` entirely. But thanks for the explanation. I may find a use for this later.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure that 0.25ex is the right choice: it actually makes the + sign to be slightly higher than a capital letter.

Using different fonts might also make the situation even worse. For instance, with Times you'd get

[image]

because here the + sign sits on the baseline. Can we make the raising independent of the font? Yes: a bit of algebra shows that we need to raise the symbol by half the sum of a capital letter, minus the height of + plus the height of +.

Using David's idea:

```
\newcommand{\+}{%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr(\fontcharht\font`X-\height+\depth)/2\relax}{+}%
}
```

Here's the output with Times

[image]

and with Computer Modern

[image]

Here's a visual proof of the statement about the height. The first + is with my definition, the second is raised 0.25ex. Just look at the top, because at the bottom TeX always uses the baseline.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

[image]

You could make + active and raise itself in text mode and not in math, but something would break, it is quite hard to catch all cases of `\dimexpr \parindent + 5pt\relax` and ensure you don't add a `\raisebox` mid-expression.

I would use a new command for it, `\+` isn't defined by default so:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\+{\raisebox{0.25ex}{+}}
\begin{document}

NNLL+NNLO


NNLL\+NNLO

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here my solution for a `+` sign between text letters (inspired in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52503/sign-in-international-phone-numbers#52517)). It has following features:

- I offer both a solution for **capital** (`\Plus`) and **lower case** (`\plus`) letters. For the lower case, I recommend to reduce the size.
- I use a different syntax.

[image]

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{calc}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    
    %Plus for lower case
    \newlength{\heightofx}
    %Plus size is reduced to 60% (0.6)
    %and set at the mid height of 'x'
    \newcommand{\plus}{\settoheight{\heightofx}{x}%
    \raisebox{0.5\heightofx-(0.5\totalheight-\depth)}%
    {\scalebox{0.6}{+}}} 
    
    %Plus for captitals
    \newlength{\heightofX}
    %Plus is set at the mid height of 'X'
    \newcommand{\Plus}{\settoheight{\heightofX}{X}%
    \raisebox{0.5\heightofX-(0.5\totalheight-\depth)}{+}} 
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
    Adapted & Raw \\
    \hline
     \\[-0.5em]
    LOVE\Plus GRACE & LOVE+GRACE\\
    love\plus grace & love+grace
    \end{tabular}
    
    \end{document}
```

Comment: like a charm, thank you.

Comment: @Duda my pleasure!